# symfony perform post query

Tags: php, symfony, http-post

I need to perform post request using using Symfony framework. I can see there is package `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` for this purpose. But when I create post request it seems doens't really perform request and return object data

```
$response = Request::create(get_api_url().'test','POST', $params);
```

How can I permorm real post request?

Comment: You can use [PHP's cURL library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: I know, but need to use native symfony packages.

Comment: The request object **is not** a "package to make requests". It's only meant to encapsulate the **received** request. You misunderstood its function. To perform a HTTP request, either use curl as suggested in a comment, or the HTTPClient if you can install it in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = HttpClient::create();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://...');
```

More details you can find [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#uploading-data)

Comment: unfortunately symfony is just a part of Shopware and there is no such library provided